Why are these Clow Cards under the Windy Card?
Hmmmm..... Aside the Float Card, the Fly Card, and the Storm Card, why are these Clow Cards (on the list below) under the Windy Card?
List:

Dash Card
Jump Card
Move Card
Song Card
Voice Card

https://ccsakura.fandom.com/wiki/Clow_Cards
I can definitely see and understand how the Float Card, the Fly Card, and the Storm Card are related to the Windy Card seeing how they are wind-based elements but do the rest have some connection with the Windy Card compared to the Float Card, the Fly Card, and the Storm?
Are there any significant reasons?

There is some abstraction going on with how some cards are groups under the Elemental Cards. for instance The Arrow and The Sword are under The Firey but Arrows and Swords are not necessarily fire by nature even though you can have flaming arrows and Swords are forged in fire
but what these both have in common is that their nature is to Attack, in a similar vein to The Power and The Fight and Fire is commonly viewed with aggression/attacking (eg. Fire Bending in Avatar, the ATK+ Fire Orbal Artes Forte/La Forte in Kiseki)
with that, We can see more why The Jump, The Dash and the Move would be under Windy as these involvement movement, something commonly associated with Wind (eg. Aang's Air Bending in Avatar, Move and Evade Quartz needing Wind Sepith in Kizeki)
for The Song and The Voice, i would guess it's because Air is needed for both of these as we are able to talk or sing due to air vibrating vocal cords in our larynx
